# I can't getting input fields in blog page but i written code for input fields in html page

Tags: python, django, input, field, blogs

I can't getting input fields in blog page but i written code for input fields in html page

First i added some reactions you may see in my page it is saved in my sql server, i want to input fields to react for my post and those reactions(comments) should be displayed in below  for my blog but input fields are hidden i am unable to see it, with my knowledge i written this below code but i can't getting input fields like email and comment box, i'm trying to display those reaction in same page index.html

'''

```
forms.py

from django import forms 
from . models import user_response


class userfield(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user_response
        fields='__all__'

models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class user_response(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    userEmail = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.userName, self.userEmail

urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('userdata/',views.userdata, name='userdata'),
]


views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from . models import user_response
from . forms import userfield

# Create your views here.

def userdata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userfield(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(request, '../templates/index.html')
    else:
        form = userfield()
    
    data = user_response.objects.all()  # Fetch user reactions
    return render(request, '../templates/index.html', {'form': form, 'data': data})


index.html

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Nebula</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Blog</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="blog-post">
            <h2>Blog Post Title 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac ex at arcu tristique ultricies.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-post">
            <h2>Blog Post Title 2</h2>
            <p>Curabitur ac justo eu sem sodales tincidunt vel vel nulla. Fusce at ex quis urna iaculis semper.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Make a reaction To know read other reactions</h1>
            <form action={% url 'userdata' %}  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{data.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>

            {% for i in data %}
            <div>
                <h6>user name : {{i.userName}}</h6>
                <h6>user email : {{i.userEmail}}</h6>
                <h6>Reaction {{i.message}}</h6>
                <hr>
            {% empty %}
                <p> No reactions </p>
            </div>
            {% endfor%}
        <div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        &copy; 2023 My Blog
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

'''